# Is it possible to memcpy contiguous HDF5 datasets?

Tags: performance, aggregate, hdf5, memcpy

I wish to aggregate several HDF5 files into one: this operation requires at some point to copy all the "source" datasets into the resulting one side-by-side.

Is there a way to do this in a memcpy-style ? The **H5Dwrite** and **H5Dread** functions would require the use of a temporary buffer and thus an additional allocation / copy / free.

*I am aware HDF5 specification allow datasets to be physically stored in chunks. But this is not the case here.*

Comment: why exactly would they require a temporary buffer? Maybe have a look at [H5Ocopy](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5O.html#Object-Copy).

Comment: OK, I was not aware of this function, though it does not seem to be able to append a dataset to an existing one. The doc states : _the copy will be created with the path specified in dst_name, which must not pre-exist in the destination location. If dst_name already exists at the location dst_loc_id, H5Ocopy will fail._

Comment: For this you have to read the dataset to append. You can work with only a part of a dataset at a time. Partial datasets are called hyperslabs in HDF5. The Python package h5py is a good solution for this.